# inserting a new object after updating an account

Tags: apex, trigger, insert

I am trying to insert a new custom object called `Aid` if 2 CheckBoxes in an account are checked.

here is my trigger:

```
trigger Aid on Account (before update) {
for(Account acc: Trigger.new) {

    if(acc.is_old == true && acc.is_poor  == true) {
        Aid aid = new Aid();
        aid.Pogram_name__c   = 'a0RD000000E****';
        aid.Item__c          = 'a10D0000000****';
        aid.Supplier__c      = 'a0zD0000000****';
        aid.Household__c     =  acc.id;
        insert aid;
    }

}
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Apex trigger Aid caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator:  Aidexecution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
>   System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>
> First exception on row 0; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER,
>   Object (id = 001D000001x****)  is currently in trigger Aid therefore
>   it cannot recursively update itself: []: Trigger.Aid: line 10, column
>   1**

what am i doing wrong???

Comment: Is there any trigger on Aid. Also there should be __c in Aid name?

Comment: @Ashwani , yes there should be _ c. i just shortened it for here..  no triggers on aid..

Comment: Try with an after update.

Comment: @MartinLezer i get this::Apex trigger Aid caused an unexpected exception,
 contact your administrator: Aid execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. 

First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,

 PersonAccount trigger event AfterUpdate for [001D000001x****] PersonAccount trigger event AfterUpdate for

 [001D000001x**** PersonAccount trigger event AfterUpdate for 
...............................................................
PersonAccount trigger event AfterUpdate for [001D000001x****]: []: Trigger.Aid: line 12, column 1

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is trigger on Aid, that cause an update on child AID records (or flow/processbuilder/workflow etc), so loop appears

Comment: As @kurunve said is right.And try to avoid DML operation inside a loop.